# “Church Catholic” versus “Catholic Church” is the first form acceptable?

Tags: nouns, word-order, compound-adjectives, convention

I heard both expressions, but the first sounds more "creedal". Although, just the second is fine according to the English language norms. When is "Church Catholic" fine to be used? The Merriam Webster *[definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catholic)* writes **church universal** in the same way.

Edit:
Here's a quote from *[Solo Scriptura, Sola Scriptura, and Apostolic Succession](http://turretinfan.blogspot.ro/2011/02/solo-scriptura-sola-scriptura-and.html)* by Keith Mathison

> "Well, all available historical evidence indicates that the Roman Magisterium did apostatize. But the Roman Magisterium is not identical to the **Church Catholic** so the Church was not overcome when this occurred. The Catholic Church continued to exist even when the local Magisterium of Rome joined the gates of hell in an attempt to prevail against her. While the bishops of Rome and the Roman Magisterium were busy deserting the sheep entrusted to them and abandoning the doctrine of the Apostles with which the Church of Rome (and all of the other local churches) had been entrusted, the Catholic Church continued. Believing Christians in the Western Church were deserted by their shepherds, who were more interested in worldly gain than they were in spiritual things, [FN13] but the desertion of the sheep by their shepherds did not destroy the church. It survived the apostasy of these “priests” just as the Old Testament church survived the apostasy of her priests."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70296/discussion-on-question-by-dani-pop-church-catholic-versus-catholic-church-is).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Linguistically, the terms *Catholic Church* and *church catholic* (alternatively *Church catholic* or *Church Catholic*) are not interchangeable.

The former refers to the theological tradition and religious institution headed by the Bishop of Rome (“the” Pope, in Western Civilization), often called the *Roman Catholic Church*, whereas the latter refers to the idealized concept of the body of all Christian believers.

---

**Full answer:**

First of all, on a purely grammatical note, the use of post-positive adjectives is well attested in English. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective) provides the following handy list of set phrases with post-positive adjectives relating to *Legal and general terms*:

> **Legal and general terms**: agent provocateur, battle royal, body corporate, body politic, corporation sole, cause célèbre, court-martial, fee simple, fee tail, femme fatale, force majeure, God Almighty, heir apparent, heir presumptive, knight errant, language isolate, letters close, letters patent, letters testamentary, life everlasting, the light fantastic, malice aforethought (also *malice prepense*), persona non grata, mens rea, pound sterling, proof positive, spaghetti bolognese, sum total, time immemorial, times past, treasure trove

This might lead us to believe that *Catholic Church* and *church catholic/Church Catholic* can be used interchangeably, where the second is merely an arcane, flowery or more literary version of the first. ***This is emphatically not the case***.

The modern term *catholic* is derived from the Greek words *kata* and *holos* meaning *about* and *(the) whole* respectively. The word *catholic*, in theological terms means something like *all embracing, universal, all encompassing* and has connotations of both inclusivity and diversity.

Nowadays, however, *Catholic* is more commonly associated with the particular Christian church headed by the Bishop of Rome, often and especially historically also called the *Roman Catholic Church* (after the Roman Rite, by which Western adherents worship almost exclusively. There are Byzantine Catholics, Syriac Catholics, Chaldean Catholics, and so on, but until the modern era, few were to be found in English-speaking countries). Thus, being referred to as *Catholic* or *a Catholic* is commonly interpreted as equivalent to being a member of ***the*** [Roman] Catholic Church.

However, the idea of the catholicity of the Christian religion predates the institution of the Church of Rome. Various branches of Christianity stake equal claims to be the true expression of catholicity. Consider, per Wikipedia:

- The Eastern Orthodox Church, also known as the Orthodox Church, or officially as the Orthodox Catholic Church… teaches that it is the One, Holy, Catholic and Apostolic church established by Jesus Christ in his Great Commission… .

In addition to this, many Christians who are members of other churches also regard themselves as being part of the *catholic* faith in the sense of belonging to one universal overarching inclusive body of Christian believers.

This distinction between being *catholic/Catholic* and *Catholic/Roman Catholic* is brought out in the passage that the Original Poster (henceforth *OP*) quotes from. [Here is a salient excerpt](http://turretinfan.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/solo-scriptura-sola-scriptura-and.html):

- One of the most frustrating difficulties encountered in discussions such as this is the fact that the starting assumptions of *Roman Catholics* and *non-Roman Catholics* are so different. (emphasis mine)

Perhaps to draw out the distinction further, take this passage by John Gargev from the book [*Why a Church catholic?*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KLN0NsY8m3MC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22church+catholic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifqqfK0IvYAhXFWhQKHXOAD9gQ6AEIRjAG#v=onepage&q=%22church%20catholic%22&f=false):

> > Simply put my thesis is that it has never been more important than at present for Christians to be catholic. Just to state such a proposition will surely raise the hackles of many a reader, but I am convinced that it is true and thoroughly defensible. Of course, the proposition needs explanation and qualification  and the first chapter attempts to provide such. For the moment, I am satisfied to set forth plainly the major contention which subsequent chapters will try to explain and establish.
> >
> > One qualification needs to be made at once, however. The word "catholic" in the title is written with a small letter. It is not a proper noun, naming a particular church, but an adjective describing the church of Jesus Christ wherever it is found. Many Christians who are not Roman Catholics profess faith in the holy, *catholic*  church according to the ancient creeds, so the Catholic Church (with capital letters) does not hold exclusive title to the name.
>
> (page 1)

Now, obviously there can be a problem with using the term *Catholic Church/Catholic church* if a writer wants to make it clear that they are talking about the principle of an all embracing and universal church, a body of believers, even a body of churches. The reason for this is that it could easily be interpreted as referring to the specific institution which calls itself the Catholic Church, as opposed to the notion or ideal of a catholic church in principle or referring to a notional broader church (where church is perhaps best read as a body of people). Writers who wish to avoid this confusion or to make the distinction clear will often refer to the latter as the *church catholic* to distinguish it clearly from meaning simply *the Roman Catholic Church*. This distinction is not only made by writers discussing different churches, but could easily be used by Catholic writers themselves where they might argue, for example, that the the real church catholic actually *is* the Roman Catholic Church.

Note that for many writers the term *church catholic* has a similar meaning to *the body politic*. The term *body politic* is not used so much to refer to a discrete individual political body, but all the institutions and individuals involved in politics conceived of as an overarching body. Similarly the church catholic may be seen as encompassing all the individual churches and believers who are part of an overarching inclusive body of believers.

---

---

**Note:** I am not religious and am not a theologian. The finer points of these distinctions may well be lost on me, and I hope not to have misrepresented any of the facts here. My interest in the terminology is merely linguistic.

Comment: That's really nice.  My reading was taking me in a similar direction but you found a much better source (and I didn't have the patience to plod through the ones I found).

Comment: Digging through the answers, I see it's somehow a theological matter too :)

Comment: @DaniPop Yes, it's kind of language meets culture meets theology, I suppose!

Comment: Quite. I always had a vague idea that the Roman Catholic Church did consider themselves the church catholic.

Comment: "Roman Catholic Church" is not really interchangeable with *Catholic Church*; it's a term used because conveniently, the Roman Rite is virtually the only surviving rite in Western Catholicism. Eastern Catholics (e.g. Melkites, Maronites, Byzantines, Syro-Malabars) are in full communion with Rome and recognize the authority of the pope (unlike Eastern Orthodox, Oriental Orthodox, or Protestants), but would object to being called Roman. "Greek" Catholics and "Latin" Catholics are equally Catholic.

Comment: @choster Feel free to edit post to make it more accurate or generally better :) As indicated in my postscript, I am not knowledgeable about this area!

Comment: Very well-argued answer, Araucaria. There is an interesting echo of "the church catholic" in the term "[persons religious](https://books.google.com/books?id=1GidAAAAMAAJ&q=%22persons+religious%22&dq=%22persons+religious%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE_5zQgo3YAhWIMGMKHWcCCtcQ6AEITjAI)"—which I first encountered in the early 1980s, when I became familiar (but not too familiar) with several nuns teaching at a girls' high school in Staten Island, New York. The nuns used the term to refer to people who were dedicated, in one way or another, to a life of religion-directed service to God.

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks, I took a stab at it, but I hope 1) I haven't made a hash of the answer, 2) that this doesn't inspire others to start making nitpicky tweaks on theological points here or elsewhere. The name of the Wikipedia head article was a [highly contentious dispute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Catholic_Church/Archive_30) even by the standards of Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "Church Catholic" might be used in an arcane rhetorical flourish or in a poetic sense - it is as "acceptable" as most inversions of the usual adjective-noun arrangement.

However, the phrase is not used in the English speaking **Catholic Church**.

Comment: Conventionally in English, we put adjectives before the noun. "big dog", not "dog big", etc. "Church" is a noun. "Catholic" is an adjective that modifies that noun. So as @Rob_Ster says, someone might say "Church Catholic" to be poetic or rhetorical, but it's not the normal way English-speakers talk. I don't recall ever seeing or hearing "Church Catholic" before this post.

Comment: Me neither, @Jay - and I've been working in an RC institution for four decades...

Comment: The truth is, I heard this form, Church Catholic, only in Protestant contexts. But again, it seems rather a linguistic problem then a theological one.

Comment: @Rob_Ster I take it you mean CR institutions -- Catholic Roman. :-)

Comment: @DaniPop I've been a Protestant for decades and I don't recall ever hearing it. Maybe it's used in other denominations, or some context I don't normally read about? When Protestants I know what to talk about all Christians, we say "the universal Church", or simply "the Church" with a capital-C. When we want to talk about the group headquartered in Vatican City, we say "the Catholic Church" or "the Roman Catholic Church", occasionally other terms. But I've never heard "Church Catholic" for either idea. Not saying no one says it, but it's obscure at best.

Answer (score 1):

In the sense meant in the question, it's [not completely unknown](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=church+corporate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchurch%20corporate%3B%2Cc0) (ngrams, useful for its links to book searches), but seems to be most common in the 19th century.  Sources appear to be both Catholic and Protestant, but with a bias towards Britsh writers.

> It was the confounding the *church catholic* and its immunities, with the *church corporate* and its obligations and privileges, which really lay at the root of all the errors entertained, and all the embarrassments experienced in this question

*Ten Years of the Church of Scotland from 1833 to 1843: With Historical Retrospect from 1560, Volume 1, James Bryce Bryce (1850)* (emphasis mine)

> And, hence, they who maintain the theory that the Anglican, Greek, and Roman branches make up, together, the *Church Catholic*, cannot stop here, even if they would; for the fact of one division authorizes division ad infinitum

*Submission to the Catholic Church, Anthony John HANMER (1850)* (again, emphasis mine)

Highlighted in the first quote is the simliar construction *Church Corporate* which I recollect being used in a nonconformist sense to mean *Church* as a body of people (as opposed to a building)

One odd case is when *church* is used to modify a noun *Catholic* to mean a proper practicing Catholic. A rather contrived example: "Alice still calls herself a Catholic, though she only turns up at Christmas; Bob is a Church Catholic, he's in there every day".

I've heard this use in speech and it might confuse searches if it occurs much in writing.

Comment: I have a vague memory of similar constructions being used to describe the *Church* in the sense of a body of believes, compared to *Church* as a building. Google isn't helping as it regards "church" and "church's" as synonymous in a quoted phrase. I think "Church Corporate" might be been one term, in a nonconformist setting. This was going to be in the answer but I've taken it out; it might still jog someone's memory.

Comment: I really appreciate your heavy work Chris!

Comment: @DaniPop that's OK.  It just needed a few minutes in front of a computer instead of on mobile.  I'll clean up my previous comments